# Can I pass the limit under the integral?

Tags: limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I couldn't find the question on the website.

I need to determine the integral $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\int_{\left[
0,1\right] }f_{n}d\mu $, if it exists, where $\mu $ is the Lebesgue measure
and
$$
f_{n}=\frac{\sin \left( \left( x+\frac{1}{n}\right) ^{2}\right) -\sin \left(
\left( x-\frac{1}{n}\right) ^{2}\right) }{\sin \frac{1}{n}}
$$
Now I can see that
$$\frac{\sin \left( \left( x+\frac{1}{n}\right)
^{2}\right) -\sin \left( \left( x-\frac{1}{n}\right) ^{2}\right) }{\sin 
\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{\sin \left( \left( x+\frac{1}{n}\right) ^{2}\right) -\sin
\left( \left( x-\frac{1}{n}\right) ^{2}\right) }{\frac{2}{n}}2\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sin \frac{1}{n}}$$
and using the fact that $g^{\prime }\left( x\right)
=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g\left( x+h\right) -g\left( x-h\right) }{2h}$
for $g\left( x\right) =\sin \left( x^{2}\right) $ and that $\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\sin \frac{1}{n}}\longrightarrow 1$, we conclude that $f_{n}\longrightarrow 4x\cos x^{2}$ but I am having trouble moving the limit
under the integral sign. What I think is that, since this sequence of
functions converges pointwise, they must be bounded by a finite function $%
m\left( x\right) $, which is Lebesgue integrable and then we can apply the
DCT. Is this okay? I tried to show that convergence is uniform but my hand
wouldn't move.

Comment: You would have to find a dominating function. Since the integral is on $[0,1]$ maybe try $|f_n| \leq 4$ (but I am not sure if this works, it's just a good starting point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, pointwise convergence of $f_n$ does not imply the existence of dominating functions. But in this case it is easy.

Note

\begin{align}
\frac{g(x+h) - g(x-h)}{2h} &= \frac 12 \frac{g(x+h) - g(x)}{h} + \frac 12 \frac{g(x) - g(x-h)}{h}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} (g'(x_1) +g'(x_2))
\end{align}

by the Mean Value Theorem. Since $|g'|\le 2$ on $[0,1]$, we see that $|f_n|\le 8$ when $n$ is large enough. Thus you can apply Dominate Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Ah, the forgotten MVT. Thank you, good person.